# How to Adjust the <td> size when having no access to the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please have a look at the fiddle below, the top row is not ordered correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/J7WPb/1/

Once if you see, you will understand the problem.

EDIT: As the comment below says, user936625 doesn't have access to the HTML and cannot delete the faulty line. He is looking for a "script" as a solution.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Do jQuery selectors return elements you expect? Are there exceptions being thrown?

Answer (score 3):

You have colspan=2 on the 3rd line.. It should not span 2:

http://jsfiddle.net/J7WPb/8/

Comment: The `colspan=2` is present in all of the `<tr>`s if I looked correctly.

Comment: Very thanks for your fiddle. But i don't have access to HTMl to add that colspan manually.. I need to remove that colspan through script. How can i remove that..

Comment: The jquery-created `<th>` have a colspan=2, but they are the ones that say **one**, or **two** -- so their colspan doesn't matter.

Comment: problems come from the fact that you're hiding the category text... this removes a `<td>` that's relied on by previous `colspan=2`. I updated my answer with correct solution

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you want to `colspan="2"` on the first cell? this is what causes the table to be bad

Comment: No, I dont want that colspan=2..Please help me to remove that

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`<td colspan="2" id="Cell.0.0">`

to:

`<td id="Cell.0.0">`

Comment: No, I dont want that colspan=2..Please help me to remove that

Comment: make the change ive suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden columns (e.g. "Cell.0.1") are ignored when calculating colspans, so your cells with `colspan=2` actually span into the answer columns.  Remove the `colspan`, and it should work.

Comment: No, I dont want that colspan=2..Please help me to remove that